# can synchronized at method level be replaced by Lock?

Tags: java, concurrency

When writing a thread safe class, we use `synchronized` keyword at two places in code,

1.Method level synchronization

2.Synchronized blocks

As far as I can think of, interfaces like `Lock` (`java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock`)can be used in place of `synchronized`only at block level but not at method level. or is there a way?

I don't have any real need of it but just curios since heard discussions that `Lock`can be a replacement for `synchronized`.

```
public class SampleClass {
    public synchronized void method(){
      .....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no special syntax for "acquire the Lock at the beginning of the method, and release it at the end," like there is for `synchronized`.

You can, of course, just do that yourself:

```
public void method() {
    lock.lock();
    try {
        // rest of the method
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As we all know

```
public class SampleClass {
    public synchronized void method(){
      .....
    }
}
```

and

```
public class SampleClass {
    public void method(){
        synchronized(this) {
           .....
        }
    }
}
```

is equivalent for all practical purposes.

So you need to change method synchronization to equivalent block synchronization and the later can be replaced by `Lock`

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way to do this since `java.util.concurrent`—and therefore `Lock` or any other implementation as well—is just a library, whereas `synchronized` is part of the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.1).

Regarding "`Lock` can be a replacement for synchronized", Brian Goetz discusses this in ["Java Concurrency in Practice"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601) in chapter 13.4:

> `ReentrantLock` is an advanced tool for situations where intrinsic locking is not practical. Use it if you need its advanced features: timed, polled, or interruptible lock acquisition, fair queueing, or non-block-structured locking. Otherwise, prefer synchronized.